# Can't make deploy of .net api with railway

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, docker, deployment

I'm kind of stuck with this problem. I've developed my API with .NET and I'm trying to deploy it with Railway since Heroku is no longer free. First, I tried to deploy it with Docker file and Railway was able to deploy it, but I can't access the API with the domain that it generated for me. So, I'm unable to access it.
Here's my Program.cs:

```
using Aplicacao.Interfaces;
using Aplicacao.Services;
using Dominio.Mensagem;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Repositorio.Interfaces;
using Repositorio.Repositories;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Configuration.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
builder.Configuration.AddKeyPerFile(directoryPath: "/run/secrets", optional: true);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ConexaoBanco>();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options => { options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true; });
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader());
});
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    { Title = "ApiLoginUsuario", Version = "1.0" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme.",
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                          new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                          {
                              Reference = new OpenApiReference
                              {
                                  Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                  Id = "Bearer"
                              }
                          },
                         new string[] {}
                    }
                }); ;
});
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMensagem, Mensagem>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUsuarioRepository, UsuarioRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITokenService, TokenService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
var tokenDecriptor = builder.Configuration["Secrets:TokenKey"];
Console.WriteLine(tokenDecriptor);
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tokenDecriptor);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
});
var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

app.MapControllers();


app.Run();
```

Here's the Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 7028

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ApiLoginUsuario/ApiLoginUsuario.csproj", "ApiLoginUsuario/"]
COPY ["Aplicacao/Aplicacao.csproj", "Aplicacao/"]
COPY ["Repositorio/Repositorio.csproj", "Repositorio/"]
COPY ["Dominio/Dominio.csproj", "Dominio/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ApiLoginUsuario/ApiLoginUsuario.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ApiLoginUsuario"
RUN dotnet build "ApiLoginUsuario.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ApiLoginUsuario.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN rm -rf /app/build
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ApiLoginUsuario.dll"]
```

Here's de deploy log
[deploy log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jhe2.png)
And finally here's the result when try to access the domain
[Result domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PdBr.png)

Until now I've tryed to deploy without the Dockerfile, didn't work, with Dockerfile it was able to deploy but i can't access or make any request with postman, getting 405 method not allowed.

Comment: 403 *might* be correct, since you `AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer" ,...`. Are you sending a Bearer token with your request from Postman?

Comment: Hi! No I don't, because the method I'm trying to test is the login method, that allow anonymous requests. Running the application local it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Add this code at the start of your program.cs, after your

> var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

```cs
if (builder.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    var portVar = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT");
    if (portVar is { Length: > 0 } && int.TryParse(portVar, out var port))
    {
        builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.ListenAnyIP(port);
        });
    }
}
```

The 503 error is because Railway fails to access the application inside the container, normaly because a port issue.